# Grasping 3NF - Is this an indicator of a 3nf database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

So, from my understanding, in a 3nf database, the primary key value can be used to determine every single other attribute in the table.

1. Does this mean foreign keys will exclusively be used to create composite entities? How do foreign keys fit in a 3nf database?

What are some 'signs' that my database is normalised? Can some tables in a database be normalised, while others are not?

Comment: *"So, from my understanding, in a 3nf database, the primary key value can be used to determine every single other attribute in the table."* No. That's trivially true for *all* normal forms. A table is in 3NF if it's in 2NF and there are no transitive dependencies.

Comment: FKs have nothing to do with whether a table or database is in a given NF. And a database being in a NF is just informal talk for all of its tables being in at least that NF. (You need to read a college/university textbook and find out what normalization (to higher NFs) is.)

Comment: <opinion>NF is just a textbook game; real life ignores such.</opinion>

Comment: @RickJames If there are invalid values for a table then they should identified and dealt with. Normalization to 5NF in design is part of doing so for an important class of invalidities. Your opinion does not reflect an understanding of that. But normalization is poorly taught so it's unfortunately a common opiniion.

Answer (score 1):

> So, from my understanding, in a 3nf database, the primary key value can be used to determine every single other attribute in the table.

Not really. That's trivially true for *all* normal forms. A table is in 3NF if it's in 2NF and there are no transitive dependencies. Strictly speaking, the normal forms refer to individual tables, not to databases.

> Does this mean foreign keys will exclusively be used to create composite entities? How do foreign keys fit in a 3nf database?

No. You can mix foreign key references and discrete values in any way that makes sense. Or in ways that make *no* sense.

> What are some 'signs' that my database is normalised?

The "signs" are simply the definitions of the various normal forms. Do you want to know whether my table "Users" in 3NF? Apply the definition of 3NF to it. If it meets all the criteria, it's in 3NF.

> Can some tables in a database be normalised, while others are not?

Since the normal form (1NF, 2NF, 3NF, etc) is characteristic of a table, a database might consist of tables in every possible combination of normal forms. You might have some tables in 2NF, some in 3NF, some in BCNF, some in 6NF.

Comment: Sherill 'Cat Recall' Hmm, ok. If a table has two foreign keys ONLY, for the purpose of mapping two tables together, does that make that table an association entity? What if the table had two foreign keys and one attribute,willl it still be an association entity  ?

Comment: An Associative entity is a somewhat informal term in ER modelling. If an entity has more than one foreign key then arguably that qualifies as an association between the things identified by those foreign keys. Whether you call it associative or not has no relevance to whether a table is in 3NF. What matter are the attributes and the dependencies.